pip3 : unable to install python-logging but pip3 is installed. pip3 has installed pycyrptodome and routersploit before
I was trying to write some code with python when I had to install logging. However, pip install logging gave this error message :
Collecting logging
  Using cached logging-0.4.9.6.tar.gz (96 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [60 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 14, in <module>
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
          import setuptools.version
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
          import pkg_resources
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
          __import__('pkg_resources.extern.packaging.specifiers')
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/specifiers.py", line 24, in <module>
          from .utils import canonicalize_version
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/utils.py", line 8, in <module>
          from .tags import Tag, parse_tag
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/tags.py", line 5, in <module>
          import logging
        File "/tmp/pip-install-umhd7r1z/logging_34dc47ab9a324c678e534978bacd3d8e/logging/__init__.py", line 618
          raise NotImplementedError, 'emit must be implemented '\
                                   ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      Error in sys.excepthook:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 72, in apport_excepthook
          from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
          from apport.report import Report
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 32, in <module>
          import apport.fileutils
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 28, in <module>
          from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 23, in <module>
          import apt
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
          from apt.package import Package as Package, Version as Version
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/package.py", line 24, in <module>
          import logging
        File "/tmp/pip-install-umhd7r1z/logging_34dc47ab9a324c678e534978bacd3d8e/logging/__init__.py", line 618
          raise NotImplementedError, 'emit must be implemented '\
                                   ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      
      Original exception was:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 14, in <module>
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
          import setuptools.version
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
          import pkg_resources
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 77, in <module>
          __import__('pkg_resources.extern.packaging.specifiers')
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/specifiers.py", line 24, in <module>
          from .utils import canonicalize_version
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/utils.py", line 8, in <module>
          from .tags import Tag, parse_tag
        File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/tags.py", line 5, in <module>
          import logging
        File "/tmp/pip-install-umhd7r1z/logging_34dc47ab9a324c678e534978bacd3d8e/logging/__init__.py", line 618
          raise NotImplementedError, 'emit must be implemented '\
                                   ^
      SyntaxError: invalid syntax
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.



anyone knows how to fix this?
the last time I used pip is when I installed routersploit with pip install routersploit I also tried using force with pip install --force logging but the same thing happened. I am currently using Bash on Backbox Linux.

if you're trying to install logging module of python, it's inbuilt, and you can import it directly to your code if you've python installed

Does this answer your question? Error while installing logging package on Anaconda Prompt

The logging package on pypi hasn't been updated in over 10 years and that ancient code not being compatible with modern python creates the error. The reason it hasn't been updated is that it has become part of the standard library of python that is always available. The preferred way to use it is to not install anything and just import logging.
